# Declaration of array in c

Tags: c, heap-memory, stack-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack variables vs. Heap variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258724/stack-variables-vs-heap-variables)

What is the difference between declaring an array as:

```
int arr[100];
```

and

```
int* arr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

Which one is preferred? Is there something like heap and stack memory involved in this?

Comment: @JSBangs : Yes, Stack variables vs. Heap variables precisely answers my question. Thank you for directing me there.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a trip to the bookstore to pickup a copy of Kernighan and Ritchie's *The C Programming Language*, and optionally, a copy of Harbison & Steele's *C: A Reference Manual*.

The first case gives you an array of 100 ints, allocated on the stack. The latter case gives you a pointer to an int, whose address is that of a buffer allocated on the heap, the size of which is large enough to contain 100 ints.

The C language is fundamentally a hardware agnostic assembly language. The distinction between a pointer and an array is intentionally fuzzy, since array reference notation is syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic. This:

```
int foo( int a )
{
  int x[100] = load_X() ;
  int y = x[ a ] ;
  return y ;
}
```

is identical to

```
int foo( int a )
{
  int *x     = load_X() ;
  int y      = *( x + a ) ;
  // note that the use of sizeof() isn't required.  For the pointer carries around
  // an implicit increment size (the size of the object to which it points). The above
  // is equivalent to
  //
  //   int y = *(int*)((char*)x + (a*sizeof(*x)) ) ;
}
```

Further, the compiler will (or should) whine about type mismatches, given function `foo()`:

```
public void foo( int a[] )
{
  ...
}
```

The invocation:

```
int *p = malloc(...) ;

foo(p) ;
```

should results in a compiler whine regarding type mismatches.

Answer (score 1):

The first one declares `arr` as an *array* of type `int[100]` that resides on the stack. In some contexts `arr` will decay to a pointer of type `int *`, but that doesn't make it a pointer. To further emphasize that it is not a pointer, `sizeof(arr)` will yield `sizeof(int) * 100`, not the size of an address.

The second one declares a *pointer* of type `int *` and initializes it to the pointer returned by `malloc`, which in fact allocates memory on the heap. Note that in this case `arr` is **not an array** - you can use the array notation to offset and dereference the pointer, but that doesn't make it an array.

Answer (score 0):

The former allocates an automatic array of size 100, which will be *automatically* released once it goes out of scope.

The latter allocates space for 100 `int`s in the free store, and returns a pointer to the start of the block of memory. It will remain allocated until `free()` is called on the pointer.

If you need the memory only for as long as the current scope, then the former is easier to work with (assuming it's not too big.) Otherwise, the latter option is the approach to take.