# Transferring variables using structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I want to transfer few variables using structure. Following is the sample program code.  When I run this program, I get segmentation fault. I use gcc compiler.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
struct data{
    const char * ip;
    const char * address;
    const char * name;
};

int fun(struct data *arg) {
    //struct data *all;
    const char *name = arg->name;
    printf("\n My name is:%s",name);
    return 1; 
}


int main(int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    struct data * all;   
    int k=0;
    //data.name = argv[1];

    all->name=argv[1];
    k = fun(all);

    printf("\n k is:%d ",k);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C: malloc your pointers. By declaring a pointer you're not allocating memory for it automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
struct data * all;
all->name=argv[1];
```

You have not allocated memory for `all`. When you have an uninitialized pointer, it is pointing to random locations in the memory, which you probably won't have access to. You have two options:

1. Allocate on the stack:

   ```
   struct data all;
   all.name=argv[1];
   k = fun(&all);
   ```
2. Allocate on the heap:

   ```
   struct data *all = malloc(sizeof(*all));
   if (all != NULL)
   {
       all->name=argv[1];
       k = fun(all);
   }
   free(all);
   ```

The first case is good when you know that `all` will be needed only in the current function (and those you call). Therefore, allocating it on the stack is sufficient.

The second case is good for when you need `all` outside the function creating it, for example when you are returning it. Imagine a function initializing `all` and return it for others to use. In such a case, you can't allocate it on the stack, since it will get destroyed after the function returns.

You can read more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258724/912144).

Comment: Thank you very much. This information not only worked my current problem but also helped me through my basic concepts. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate memory and assign it to the pointer `all`:

```
struct data * all;   
int k=0;
all = malloc(struct data);

all->name=argv[1];
k = fun(all);
//...
free(all);
```

or use a local struct and pass its pointer to the function:

```
struct data all;   
int k=0;

all.name=argv[1];
k = fun(&all);
```

Answer (score 2):

`all` is a pointer to type `struct data`.  You never assigned it, so it doesn't point to anything.

You need to do one of the following:

- allocate `all` on the stack:

  `struct data all;`
- allocate `all` on the heap:

```
    struct data* all = malloc(sizeof (struct data));   
    // don't forget to check if the allocation succeeded, 
    //and don't forget to free it when you're done
```