# Implementing simple high and low pass filters in C

Tags: c, filter, signal-processing, portaudio

Trying to use portaudio to record some data, then use an algorithmic filter to change the recorded voice and then play it back. I've verified a lot of it (coming from example) but I'm quite new to C and I think in my filter implementation I've done something silly.

```
#if LOW_PASS 
{
    float RC = 1.0/(CUTOFF*2*3.14);
    float dt = 1.0/SAMPLE_RATE;
    float alpha = dt/(RC+dt);
    float filteredArray[numSamples];
    filteredArray[0] = data.recordedSamples[0];
    for(i=1; i<numSamples; i++){
        filteredArray[i] = filteredArray[i-1] + (alpha*(data.recordedSamples[i] - filteredArray[i-1]));
    }
    data.recordedSamples = filteredArray;
}
#endif
#if HIGH_PASS
{
    float RC = 1.0/(CUTOFF*2*3.14);
    float dt = 1.0/SAMPLE_RATE;
    float alpha = RC/(RC + dt);
    float filteredArray[numSamples];
    filteredArray[0] = data.recordedSamples[0];
    for (i = 1; i<numSamples; i++){
        filteredArray[i] = alpha * (filteredArray[i-1] + data.recordedSamples[i] - data.recordedSamples[i-1]);
    }
    data.recordedSamples = filteredArray;
}
#endif
```

When the recorded signal tries to go through these filters I get something the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./paex_record: free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfd68600 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb75e2ee2]
./paex_record[0x8048fe5]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb75864d3]
./paex_record[0x80487f1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2363767    /home/svictoroff/Documents/CompArch/portaudio/examples/paex_record
...
bfd68000-bff1a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm just really not sure what's going on here. Any thoughts?
Free is called from the end of the script at terminate here:

```
Pa_Terminate();
    if( data.recordedSamples )       /* Sure it is NULL or valid. */
        free( data.recordedSamples );
    if( err != paNoError )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
        err = 1;          /* Always return 0 or 1, but no other return codes. */
    }
    return err;
```

Comment: What is the size of *recordedSamples* ?

Comment: The error appears to occur inside a call to `free`.  Can you show the code that calls `free` too please?

Comment: RecordedSamples is around 200k

Comment: Ah, found the free, posting now.

Comment: Can you show the line of code the error happens at then please?  You could determine this using a debugger or by adding `printf` statements through your code

Comment: This line: data.recordedSamples = filteredArray; will cause you a big memory leak if you do not keep another reference towards the recordedSamples array.

Comment: How exactly should I change it to avoid that problem?

Comment: The line axeoth highlighted would also cause a crash if other code tries to free data.recordedSamples.  filteredArray is a stack variable so will be freed when it goes out of scope; it cannot be freed using the (dynamic heap's) free function

Comment: How should I properly replace the contents of recorded data with filtered data to avoid these problems? Sorry, I'm pretty new to C.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: to replace data, use a for() loop and copy float by float; or use memcpy() (you need to include <string.h>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that data.recordedSamples now (at the time of `free()`) points towards a structure allocated on the stack, not on the heap!

Since you had this instruction:

```
data.recordedSamples = filteredArray;
```

The

```
if( data.recordedSamples )
```

is of no use, since the adress id valid, but not consistent: it is never allocated with `malloc()` and it is not on the heap, but on the stack!

At the moment when you are calling `free()`, that adress could well point towards the stack of another function.

Copy your filtered data back over the original `recordedSamples` if you want, just do not re-assign that pointer.

edit:

use this:

```
for(i = 0; i<numSamples; i++) {
    data.recordedSamples[i] = filteredArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, and sorry if I'm being dense, but how exactly would I do that?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: to replace data, use a for() loop and copy float by float; or use memcpy() (you need to include <string.h>); for(i = 0; i<numSamples; i++) {data.recordedSamples[i] = filteredArray[i]}

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to free a stack variable. The only time you have to call `free` is when you've previously called `malloc` (or one of its friends like `calloc`) or when the documentation for a library function you're calling says you need to free a pointer that it returns.

Incidentally, any time you do free a pointer, a good practice is to set it to NULL immediately afterwards.

Stack variables go away as soon as they're out of scope. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258724/stack-variables-vs-heap-variables) might help you understand better.